# How to Disable Pop and Imap?

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, gmail-pop

I've googled a lot but I couldn't find a good answer. I need to disable pop and imap for gmail. How can I disable gmail pop and imap?

Comment: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#settings/fwdandpop

Comment: Wrong site to ask that stuff by the way.

Comment: thanks for the solution. why is it wrong?

Comment: Because Stackoverflow is meant for programming questions.